# How to pass credentials using import statement?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, import, dynamic-import

I have a .net 4.7.2 application. It has javascript that uses import to dynamically loads more javascript.

https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import

The problem is that it is getting 401 unauthorized in the application when getting these files. I have confirmed the user running the app actually has read/write access on these files. If they visit the file directly in the browser address bar, they can see the file.

I am wondering if when doing these js import commands, is it actually passing the windows credentials to it?

Thanks

Comment: This might be interessting for you: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import/issues/60 It states that a dynamic import inside a script imported by <script src="..." crossorigin="use-credentials" /> will pass the credentials.

Comment: But I'm using the js import function.

Comment: Yes but I mean the place where you use the import function is in a JavaScript file right? So this file has to be imported somewhere into html to be used in the browser

Comment: Can you show an example of the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from [this source](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import/issues/60):

--- html

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="foo.js" crossorigin="use-credentials"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

--- script foo.js

```
// load script dynamically
const path = 'foo/bar'
const module = await import(`https://api.example.com/${path}/module.mjs`);
```

Comment: But the problem is all resources is still in the same domain. Would this still work?

Comment: External imports should work as well. You might have to disable webpack in case you use it like this import(/*webpackIgnore: true*/ 'https://api.example.com/dynamic-import.js');